# Which of the following two selectors has a higher CSS specificity?

Tags: css

Which of the following two selectors has a higher CSS specificity?

```
Selector 1 -> #object h2::first-letter

Selector 2 -> body .item div h2::first-letter:hover
```

My Answer is Selector 1, I calculated 111 for that.
Selector 2 gave me a specificity of 6.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hover over a `::first-letter`, however, all things being equal, the first selector is stronger:

```css
/* Selector 1 -> #object h2::first-letter */
#this h2::first-letter{
   color: red
}

/* Selector 2 -> body .item div h2::first-letter:hover */
body .item div h2::first-letter{
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div id="this">
    <h2>This is a title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one has a higher specificity since it actually contains an ID, which takes precedence over almost everything else.